# Node.JS - Product is not a constructor error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

My code is as follows and gets me `"message": "Product is not a constructor"` using postman.
Router seems to be properly configured but now I don't know what is the issue.
File `product constructor` is placed at the right direction. When running `node server` I get no errors in terminal.

**product constructor**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const productSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  name: String,
  price: Number
});

module.export = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);
```

**Router for POSTS**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Product = require('../models/product'); //import schema, product constructor


//POSTs to products
router.post('/', (req,res,next) => {

    //ObjectId method to add new ID
    const product = new Product({
      _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
      name: req.body.name,
      price: req.body.price
    });

    //mongoose method to save data
    product
      .save()
      .then(result => {
      console.log(result);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));

    res.status(201).json({
      message: 'sending POSTs to /products',
      createdProduct: product
    });
});
```

Comment: As a real sidenote, your code sends 201 before product was either saved or rejected by DB, which might be not what you actually want. At the very least, `res.status().json()` call should be placed inside `then`; `async/await` provides a better way of expressing the same intent.

Comment: Thank you, I will implement those soon :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be `module.exports` ([doc](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_exports)), not `module.export`:

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);
```

Right now your module essentially exports a default value (an empty object).

---

As a sidenote, Schema is expected to be used as a constructor. While the function itself is written the way it'll recall itself with proper syntax if used without `new`:

```
if (!(this instanceof Schema)) {
  return new Schema(obj, options);
}
```

... you can both avoid this (albeit miniscule) loss of performance and, what's more important, show the actual intent clearly:

```
const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  name: String,
  price: Number
});
```

Comment: It seems redefining the `productSchema` const will require further rebuild at my end as now I get `"message": "product is not defined"` error.

Comment: Not sure I got your point here. Could you create another question (to avoid putting too much info into this one)?

Comment: Is is possible to chat in Stackoverflow? I could send you entire code.

Comment: That's not how SO supposed to work. ) If you have a question, you post it so that anyone (and not just me) will be able to help you - and other people, if they have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you should create instance of Schema

```
const productSchema = /*(this --->)*/ new mongoose.Schema({
  _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  name: String,
  price: Number
});
```